Adding Comparison Annotations to Boxplots
Boxplot with Tukey Comparison Bars
I had run an ANOVA test and found that at least one of the means among my groups were statistically significantly different. As follow-up analysis, I ran a Tukey test and found which groups differed in means, and I'm hoping to illustrate this in a boxplot as presented in this paper, Effects of intermittent Pringle's manoeuvre on cirrhotic compared with normal liver:
https://academic.oup.com/bjs/article/97/7/1062/6150536?login=true
I can generate the boxplot, but I want to add bar(s) that illustrates which groups significantly differ in mean with the asterik, as highlighted in the image. Anyone know how I could approach this, ideally in SAS or R?
In SAS, I've used PROC SGPLOT to generate the boxplot, and in R, I know I can use geom_boxplot, but as for any additional annotations, I'm not sure what options are available to accomplish this.

Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is not the place to ask others to write your code for you, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it for yourself. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

In Base R you can generate these lines manually if you want more granular control, or for a quick and seemingly automated approach use ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats (among other approaches, I'm sure):
Data
df <- data.frame(DAST = 1:300,
                 Category = rep(c("Normal", "Chronic Hepatitis", "Liver Cirrhosis"), each = 100))

ggbetweenstats approach
see ?ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats for a wide range of options on how to customize
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstatsplot)

ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(df, x = Category, y = DAST)


Base R approach
Colored lines for clarity
# vertical spacing between bars
v_spacing <- c(max(df$DAST) + seq(20, 50, length.out = 3))

plot(x = as.factor(df$Category), y = df$DAST,
     xlab = NA, ylab = "D-AST", frame = FALSE)
# horizontal lines - position 1 = Chronic Hepatitis, 2 = Liver Cirrhosis, 3 = Normal
  # bars map between positions 1-2, 1-3, 2-3
segments(x0 = c(1,1,2), 
         x1 = c(2,3,3),
         y0 = v_spacing,
         xpd = TRUE,
         col = c("red", "green", "blue"))

# vertical lines
segments(x0 = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3), 
         y0 = rep(v_spacing, each = 2),
         y1 = rep(v_spacing, each = 2) - 5,
         xpd = TRUE,
         col = rep(c("red", "green", "blue"), each = 2))

# Denote significance
text("*", 
     x = c(mean(1:2), mean(c(1,3)), mean(2:3)),
     y = v_spacing + 5,
     xpd = TRUE,
     col = c("red", "green", "blue"))


